# How can employers view my CV if I haven't made it searchable?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

On the Careers site my CV is a placeholder - something I filled out just enough so the system would let me file at the $29/3 year deal. I've been planning on working on it before exposing it on the site, but according to the site an employer has already viewed the page:

[image]

Seeing as the number for "CV Search Hits" is 0, I'm assuming that my CV can be viewed directly through a URL bypassing the search. If this is true, then I consider it a bug. If a CV isn't searchable, it shouldn't be able to be seen by employers at all.

Comment: @Maxim: those are the total number of employers and searches performed. they *should* be the same for everyone.

Comment: @Kyle: oooooooh, i get it now... haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a minor issue with the way we were recording the history.  This has been resolved.

Comment: so does this mean that my CV wasn't actually viewed?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.  You might not want to make your CV searchable, but also want to be able to send the url directly to specific employers.

Though I guess that's a different thing than employers registered in the system stumbling across your CV on their own, which seems to be what happened here.

Comment: That could be useful, if the link would work for any employer, not just those on careers.so, and if you could opt-in, but in this case it's definitely a bug. I suspect that the CVs are numbered like the user accounts on SO, and I also suspect that I have a very low number, due to the fact that I registered about 10 seconds after it was announced at Boston DevDays.

Comment: That desperate for a new job, huh? ;)

Comment: uh, know anyone that's hiring? :-)